# Windows 10 App Service

Tags: service, uwp, windows-10

I am writing a UWP app that expect to have updated data from a remote, say a cloud service or a remote station or whatever.

So, I thought an obvious solution would be to write a service that will sync data periodically and UWP app will just show it.  I started reading about it and ended up reading this MSDN article about Windows 10 AppService

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service

But after reading the article, I stumble upon this portion as per screenshot below which basically tells that if my app is back-grounded (minimized or covered by another app), then the service will continue running for up to 30 seconds and then stop running.  This means after 30 seconds, my background syncing will stop:

[image]

How can I make sure that my data is being refreshed when needed even though my app is not in the foreground?

Comment: Where is your question? And please don't ask multiple questions on the same topic. Try to improve your existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your background task can only run for 30 seconds for processing information but you can make it so your background task runs ever 15 minutes to check if new information is available using a Time Trigger.

If you want your application to check more frequently you will have to use a Toast Notification that comes from a server, such as Azure Mobile App Service, AWS Simple Notification Service, etc. or you can create your own service using the WNS(windows notification service).

**Azure**
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/

**AWS**
https://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Comment: Thanks Stuart, keeping Azure and AWS out of the equation, how can above Windows 10 AppService service run for more than 30seconds if client application is backgrounded?  I am talking about AppService, not Tasks.  Thanks

Comment: Yes after 30 seconds your background sync will stop so you need to send toast notification to start it again. Or one of the other triggers to start it again